# Inserting data into a repeatable div through PHP

Tags: php, html

[JSFiddle here,](https://jsfiddle.net/0jda5ht7/) with unfunctionaing PHP obviously, but on the local host it pulls through the information just fine.

I am trying to append data in a loop into a specific set of tags, inside a di of a certain class.

For example, for every row in the the table, add a div with the class "card" and append "Title" into a H2, "description" into a P tag etc.

Anyone know how I could go about doing this? I'm googling but finding it hard to phrase my question right.

Div "Card" markup:

```
<div class="card">
  <h2>Health and Wellbeing</h2>
  <p>Sometimes you just did too much sitting not enough jumping go go go.</p>
</div>
```

PHP pull:

```
$sql = "SELECT title, description, count FROM relevant_topics";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<b>Title: </b>" . $row["title"]. " - Description: " . $row["description"]. " " . $row["count"]. "<br>"; 
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong here? The code you have works right?

Comment: just add some html markup in the echo, wrap it with some html, just like the one you did with the bold tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can echo the div markup into the PHP code like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo'<div class="card">
         <h2>'.$row["title"].'</h2>
         <p>'.$row["description"].'
     </div>';
}
```

Not sure where you want the Row['count'] though.

Also you might wanna use PDO instead of mysql, Since mysql is outdated: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Comment: Quick question, if I have a column called "class" with things like "green and "red" in the different rows, how do I addthis to the divs classname? I've tried this, but keep getting

Comment: Quick question, if I have a column called "class" with things like "green and "red" in the different rows, how do I addthis to the divs classname? I've tried this, but keep getting " unexpected '$class' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' " Turns out I can't paste code here, oops.

Comment: I don't understand your question. can u create a JSFiddle for me? So i can see the code :)

Comment: Oh maybe I understand. Try this: `echo'<div class="'. $class .'"> ';`

Note that with the `'` you will be opening and closing the echo. The `"` is purely for the CSS styling. The `.` is actually just a `+`

Comment: Figured it out :) ANd it was also exactly what you said, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// output data of each row
while($row = $result-> mysql_fetch_array()) {//if not works change mysql_fetch_array() to fetch_assoc()
    echo'<div class="card"><h2>';
    echo '.$row["title"].';
    echo '</h2><p>';
    echo '.$row["description"].';
    echo '</P></div>'; 

}
```